# Next.js 13: Customizing Next.js layouts based on route hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js 13 project where I have a route named *problems/[slug]*. On the first level of this route (e.g., *problems/react*), I have a sidebar and a content section, which I am displaying using a `layout.tsx`.

However, on the next nested level of the route (e.g., */problems/react/test-problem*), I want to use a different layout instead of the original one. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Note:** I am looking for an app directory-based approach

Comment: Don't see what the issue is. You can create separate components for `problems/react` and `problems/react/test-problem`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next JS 13 - Remove layout for specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230464/next-js-13-remove-layout-for-specific-page)

Comment: I am facing the same issues. Did you manage to solve it? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

In Next.js 13, you can use the [usePathname](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-pathname) hook to determine which page you are on and then logically show or hide it:

`const pathname = usePathname(); const show_Navbar_Sidebar = pathname === '/about' || pathname === '/signup' ? false : true;`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the structure of the pages folder as shown below

```
pages/
    problems/
      [slug]/
        - index.js      // will match for /problems/[:slug] 
        - [problem].js   // will match for /problems/[:slug]/[:problem]
```

If you need multiple layouts, you can add a property `getLayout` to your page, allowing you to return a React component for the layout. This allows you to define the layout on a per-page basis. Since we're returning a function, we can have complex nested layouts if desired.

```
// pages/problems/[slug]/index.js

import StandardLayout from '../components/StandardLayout'

export default function ProblemMainPage() {
  return (
    /** Your content */
  )
}

ProblemMainPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <StandardLayout>
      {page}
    </StandardLayout>
  )
}
```

```
// pages/problems/[slug]/[problem].js

import AnotherLayout from '../components/AnotherLayout'

export default function ProblemDetail() {
  return (
    /** Your content */
  )
}

ProblemDetail.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <AnotherLayout>
      {page}
    </AnotherLayout>
  )
}
```

Update your pages/_app.js file

```
// pages/_app.js

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

Learn more about it on Next.js documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

Comment: is this in next13?

Comment: Yes, it's in Next js 13. It supports both the `app/` and `pages/ ` directories. But the `app` directory-based layout is different and currently app-based routing is in beta.
The above solution is for the pages directory route.

Comment: i am looking for app directory based approach

Comment: Okay! I'll try to figure out the solution for the app-based directory approach. And post another solution soon.

Comment: @NikhilChauhan Thank you for your answer. It's a great solution for pages directory. But I need the same solution for the app directory. Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my comment on the post, there should be no issue in what you're trying to do.

You can create a component called `<ParentLayout />` and use it as the layout for `problems/react`, and use a different component `<ChildLayout />` for `problems/react/test-problem`.

Import the appropriate components into the respective files, and use them.

Comment: the route is folder based dynamic route.
i am using next13

Comment: @NIshamMahsin I get that the route is dynamic. But in the [parent] route, you can use `<FirstLayout />` and [parent]/[child] you can use `<ChildLayout />`

Answer (score 0):

As an **app directory-based approach**, you can solve your problem using [Route Groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups) by defining your *routes* and *layouts* under specific **groups**. In your case, you can use the following structure:

```
app
|-- problems
|   |-- [slug1]
|   |   |-- (group1)
|   |   |   |-- page.tsx        // Ex: /problems/react (slug1: react)
|   |   |   |-- layout.tsx
|   |   |-- (group2)
|   |   |   |-- [slug2]
|   |   |   |   |-- page.tsx    // Ex: /problems/react/test-problem  (slug1: react, slug2: test-problem)
|   |   |   |   |-- layout.tsx
```

Hope this can solve your problem. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -3):

To achieve different layouts for different levels of your Next.js 13 project using the app directory-based approach, you can follow the steps outlined in the blog post you provided. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it:

1. Organize Routes without Affecting the URL Path:
   Create a group to keep related routes together without affecting the URL path. For example, you can create a group for the "problems" section:

```
app
|-- (problems)
|   |-- [slug]
|   |   |-- layout.js
|   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |-- test-problem
|   |   |   |-- layout.js
|   |   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |   |-- other-components.js
```

In this example, the "problems" folder is wrapped in parentheses, indicating it's a route group. The "layout.js" file inside the "problems" folder will serve as the layout for the "problems" section.

2. Creating Multiple Root Layouts:
   If you want to create multiple root layouts for different sections of your application, you can remove the top-level "layout.js" file and add a "layout.js" file inside each route group. This is useful for creating sections with completely different UI or experiences.

For example:

```
app
|-- (marketing)
|   |-- layout.js
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- about.js
|   |-- contact.js
|-- (shop)
|   |-- layout.js
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- products.js
|   |-- cart.js
|-- homepage.js
```

In this example, we have two route groups, one for the "marketing" section and another for the "shop" section. Each group has its own "layout.js" file, defining different root layouts for each section.

3. Opting Specific Segments into a Layout:
   To opt specific routes into a layout, you can create a new route group and move the routes that share the same layout into that group.

For example, in the "shop" section, you can have the following structure:

```
app
|-- (shop)
|   |-- layout.js
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- account.js
|   |-- cart.js
|   |-- checkout.js
```

In this example, the "account" and "cart" routes share the same layout, while "checkout" doesn't. By grouping "account" and "cart" together, you can apply the "layout.js" only to those routes.

Remember that routes inside a route group should not resolve to the same URL path as other routes, as route groups don't affect the URL structure.

By following these conventions and creating route groups with specific layouts, you can achieve different layouts for different levels of your Next.js 13 project based on the app directory-based approach. This will help you organize your routes and project files effectively without impacting the URL structure.

You can read more about route groups here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34752434)