# Conditional layout in Next 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I don't get how it is possible to have different layouts on the same page in Next.js 13 with the `/app` directory.

Let's say we are at the root `http://example.com` and we want to display a layout if the user is authenticated and another if not.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next JS 13 - Remove layout for specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230464/next-js-13-remove-layout-for-specific-page)

Comment: @Emre Thanks but not ideal at all. If you do that then all your app is client side. Because you make a client component at the root (root child to be exact). This is the worst SEO practice. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You might be right but RootLayout still runs on server-side because it must be a server component. You can test it with `console.log()` method. I am not sure exactly. Actually I didn't get the question completely. I've built authenticated page before but didn't use that way.

Comment: @Emre I just want to know how to display layout conditionally based on if the user is authenticated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a page from the Next.js root layout in the app folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76251099/exclude-a-page-from-the-next-js-root-layout-in-the-app-folder)

Comment: @YoussoufOumar No it does not as such. If i follow that, and create ```(general)``` and ```(auth)``` folders with both of them their ```page.jsx```. How to send a user to ```http://example.com/(general)/page.jsx``` or ```http://example.com/(auth)/page.jsx``` ? (I get that both url should be displayed as ```http://example.com``` in the browser, that's the main goal of this question)

Comment: Yeah, actually route group should not resolve to the same URL. How are you authenticating the user? Can you show your layout code? And speaking of the previous comments, [not because your layout is client, it means all the website will be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801266/does-a-client-layout-make-everything-client-if-so-how-to-add-client-interactiv).

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Yeah i remembered that from your comment on my previous question. I need to pass only children. For now it's boilerplate code. I guess i'll use Emre first comment and pass children. I guess it's good enough this way

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Man my, I went for what i said and I'm a bit confused. Could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294320/next-js-13-context-api-conditional-layouts-and-seo-optimization please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a conditional render on server side based on auth state.

Client side may need a rerender.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [route grouping](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups) to achieve what you want to do. Each route group can contain its own specific layout, and as a bonus they do not affect the URLs generated by App Router.

Comment: Please read from the question "Let's say we are at the root and we want to display a layout if the user is authenticated and another if not.".
How do you do this with route grouping ? You cant, Next throws an error if multiple files convert to the same route.