# how to know if the app is on the not found page in nextjs 14 app router

Tags: next.js, layout, http-status-code-404, conditional-rendering, app-router

I'm encountering difficulty determining if my Next.js application is on the 404 **not-found** page within the app router. I have a functioning 404 **not-found** page that displays when the URL doesn't match any routes defined in my app's router folder. However, there's a component named `NewsLetter` in the global **layout** file, so that displays on every page, including the 404 **not-found** page. I want to exclude this component from the 404 **not-found** page and from the **newsletter-confirmation** page.

I handle the exclusion of the `NewsLetter` component on the **newsletter-confirmation** page by checking the `pathname` and returning null before the component's return code if the `pathname` is `/newsletter-confirmation`. like this below

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"

export default function Newsletter() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  // Hide newsletter subscription section if the current path is the newsletter confirmation page
  if (pathname !== "/newsletter-confirmation") return null;

  return (
    <div>
      //rest code here...
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, I encountered an issue when trying to implement a similar logic for the 404 **not-found** page. When I logged the `pathname`, I noticed that it returns the random `pathname` currently in the URL. For instance, if I type `/abcd` in the URL, I'll get the value `abcd` as the `pathname` value, making it unusable for my purposes.

I've tried searching extensively online but haven't found a solution. How can I reliably determine if my app is on the Not Found page within the app router, so I can handle the exclusion of the NewsLetter component appropriately.

I've attempted to conditionally render a `NewsLetter` component inside the **Layout** file based on whether the current page is the 404 not-found page. However, I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere online, in the documentation, or in related questions on forums. I've even posted my question on the Next.js community forum, but unfortunately, I haven't received an answer yet.

My goal is to dynamically hide the `NewsLetter` component if the current page is the 404 **not-found** page. This would allow me to create exact web design, ensuring that the `NewsLetter` component isn't displayed on the 404 **not-found** page. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230464/next-js-13-remove-layout-for-specific-page